# When switching from 1 server to another data doesn't update

Tags: java, mysql, minecraft, bungeecord

I am having troubles with saving data and switching between servers on bungee. So, I load the players data when they join the server and when they leave I save their data. So, when they leave 1 server to go to another, the mysql data (I am guessing) doesn't update fast enough before it is already loaded on the server they joined. I fixed this by updating the database everytime the users rank, kill, death etc was changed but this means I have to update everytime they get a kill, mine a block etc. I used the following code

```
try {
    PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE users SET blocks_mined = ? WHERE id = ?");
    statement.setString(1, user.getMinedBlocks());
    statement.setString(2, user.getId());
    statement.executeUpdate();
}
```

But with hundreds online mining blocks, the database would be updated a few times every second and I don't want that. I just want to know how I can fix it so I can save the data when the player leaves and load it when they join again.

Comment: There is no problem at all for the database to be updated very often, but you need to execute the queries asyncronously. What you can do is save all changes that must be made and save them every now and then, and when a player changes servers, save their information at that instant

Comment: Why don't you lock the data during the update to avoid a `select` when the users change server. If it's lock (boolean column in database for example), you send a 409 code error...

Comment: How would I lock mysql? And wouldn't it just make it that the user loader on the target server just throws an error and doesn't load?

Comment: And because it doesn't update quick enough, if I set a boolean column to true for lock, it would never load correctly.